# Temperature of Heavy whipping cream in NY cheesecake?

Tags: baking, cheesecake

I don't know if this question has been asked earlier, but tomorrow I am going to attempt making a New York style baked cheesecake for the first time. The recipe I am planning to use uses a combination of heavy whipping cream and sour cream (I will substitute it with plain Greek yogurt), and every post on the internet advises to have all ingredients at room temperature. I was wondering if whipping cream and Greek yogurt also have to be at room temperature?

I am sorry if it is a silly question but I am really intimidated by the thought of making a cheesecake. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: If it says all I would assume so @Bakingenthusiast.

Answer (score 1):

I've made NY baked cheesecake on a number of occasions and have never brought the ingredients to room temperature before mixing, (mine has cream cheese, soured cream and flour in it). That said, it does take me a good ten minutes to mix everything together (including the vanilla seeds) but I still don't think the mix is room temp when I put it in the oven.

One thing I do do, is when it's a minute off being ready, I turn off the oven, open the oven door and leave the cheesecake in the oven to cool slowly, this usually prevents the top from cracking.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not necessary to bring everything to room temperature, but it is beneficial. If you think about it, it's easier to mix everything when warm (especially the cheese - you won't end up with lumps, etc.).

One really important thing to ensure you don't get a souffle (then cracking after) is to make sure that you mix slowly and DO NOT overmix. The addition of air into the mix will ultimately cause fissures.

Also, I've posted this before - bake in a water bath for 30 minutes at 300, then turn off your oven, crack the door, and leave it all for another 30 minutes. Once that time has passed, close up the oven and turn it back on to 300 and bake another 30-45 minutes. Works every time. A big thanks to my old pastry chef for giving me that tip.